# Error adding module to project: illegal char :> at index 23

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I tried to make a new project on IntelliJ IDEA. On the gradle options, I check the Java and Kotlin/JVM libraries. After I named the project folder, there's error popped up on my screen. I use jdk 16.

[Error Adding Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTddF.png)

What's wrong with my jdk? anyone could help me?

Comment: Can you check in the Project Settings to see what JDK is set and if the it is set correctly?

Comment: how can i reach that settings?

Comment: did u mean on project structure? it said my project SDK is already set to 16, and my sdk's path, already set to where it's installed, which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2".

Comment: It looks to me like *something* is using a search path (e.g. a classpath or module path) where a simple pathname is expected.  Character 23 seems to correspond to the 2nd `:` character.  A real Windows pathname has at most one `:` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the environment variables of "JAVA_HOME" to be more specific. It didn't do it, if it's located on "C:\Program Files\Java". It'll do it if it's changed into "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2".

Comment: This error will be fixed in 2021.3 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275419